# take string input using char* in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, string, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading string from input with space character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character)

I am facing problem in taking a string(technically character array) as input.
Suppose i have the following declaration:

```
 char* s;
```

I have to input a string using this char pointer till i hit "enter", please help! 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: "C/C++" is still not a language. Decide which one you want, because the two differ in the idiomatic way of programming user interaction.

Comment: actually, i am facing this problem in both of the languages.
The reason i mentioned it as C/C++ :)

Comment: @user1916200 The solutions for the two languages are drastically different in complexity.

Comment: Well, the solution is similar but not the same, so for THIS question, which do you want the answer for?

Comment: please help me in doing so in both the languages separately.

Answer (score 9):

In both C and C++ you can use the `fgets` function, which reads a string up to the new line. For example

```
char *s=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_LEN);
fgets(s, MAX_LEN, stdin);
```

will do what you want (in C). In C++, the code is similar

```
char *s=new char[MAX_LEN];
fgets(s, MAX_LEN, stdin);
```

C++ also supports the `std::string` class, which is a dynamic sequence of characters. More about the string library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/. If you decide to use strings, then you can read a whole line by writing:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

**Where to find:** the `fgets` procedure can be found at the header `<string.h>`, or `<cstring>` for C++. The `malloc` function can be found at `<stdlib.h>` for C, and `<cstdlib>` for C++. Finally, the `std::string` class, with the `std::getline` function are found at the file `<string>`.

**Advice(for C++):** if you are not sure which one to use, C-style string or `std::string`, from my experience I tell you that the string class is much more easy to use, it offers more utilities, and it is also much faster than the C-style strings. This is a part from *C++ primer*:

```
As is happens, on average, the string class implementation executes considerably
faster than the C-style string functions. The relative average execution times on
our more than five-year-old PC are as follows:

    user            0.4   # string class
    user            2.55  # C-style strings
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to take input into this string you have to allocate memory. After that you can use gets or fgets or scanf

Comment: Bad idea to use gets! Use fgets(var, size, stdin) instead.

Comment: Yes thats true. I thought to add that point but i missed

Comment: okay, i don't know in advance as to how many characters would there be int the string. What all i know is that i have to stop processing the input as and when i hit enter

Comment: You can read one character at a time using getc and allocate memory using realloc as you read !!!

Answer (score 1):

If you think about C++, `cin.getline()` might be useful.

Comment: And there needs to be memory allocation as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use cin>>variable_name; if input is without space. For input with space use gets(variable_name) in c++

Comment: If your compiler compiles code that uses `gets`, get rid of the compiler.

If you have an application that you *know* to be one that uses `gets`, get rid of that application.

If you or anyone you know actually *recommends* `gets`, (get him/her/them to) take a look at the [Wikipedia entry for buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Answer (score 0):

the `s` should be allocated before starting filling on it

1) If you do not know in advance the size of inputed string you can use `realloc`

```
char* s = calloc(1,sizeof(char));
char t;
int len;
while(scanf("%c", &t)==1)
{
  if(t== '\n')
     break;
   len = strlen(s);
   s= realloc(s,len+1);
   *(s+len) = t;
   *(s+len+1) = '\0';
}
```

2) Now If you know in advance the size of your input string max length, you can read directly your string into an array of char with scanf in this way:

```
char s[256] // Let's assume that the max length of your input string is 256

scanf("%[^\r\n]",s) // this will read your input characters till you heat enter even if your string contains spaces
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm, since the OP has stated:

*I have to input a string using this char pointer till i hit "enter"*

Thought I'd give this a shot, top of my head, this is a dynamic buffer, using `malloc` and `realloc` using pointers. However, it may contain bugs, but the gist is there! Nitpicky aside...

Apologies if the code does look awful... ::)

```
char *ptr = NULL, *temp_ptr = NULL;
int c = 0, chcount = 0, enter_pressed = 0;
do{
   c = fgetc(stdin);
   if (c != '\n' || c != -1){
     chcount++;
     if (ptr == NULL){
         ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) + chcount + 1);
         if (ptr != NULL) ptr[chcount] = c;
         else printf("ABORT!\n");
     }else{
         temp_ptr = realloc(ptr, chcount + 1);
         if (temp_ptr != NULL){
            ptr = temp_ptr;
            ptr[chcount] = c;
         }else{
            // OK! Out of memory issue, how is that handled?
            break;
         }
     }
   }else{
      enter_pressed = 1;
   }
}while (!enter_pressed);
ptr[chcount] = '\0'; // nul terminate it!
```

Comment: As I have stated - its top of my head in what the OP is looking for and did warn that the code may be awful to look at :)

Comment: Kill the `malloc()` and just make sure `ptr` is NULL on inception (which it is).

Comment: @WhozCraig your comment, the last wording, inception? Oo

Comment: i.e. make sure its initialized to NULL prior to the start of the loop (and yours is NULL, so good). `realloc()` behaves like `malloc()` when the input pointer is NULL. (side note: its a common joke that one can implement most-all the C memory allocation functions using just `realloc()` and preprocessor macros).

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I am aware of `realloc` and had to use it separately as not to confuse - in fact `realloc` is a classic example of function *overload* ;)