# Input a string from console using Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to enter a string (or a number of integers) from the command line using Objective C. These numbers are separated by a space.

Sample Input: 1 2 3 4 5

I am trying the code

```
char input[100] = {0};
NSString *inputString;
scanf("%s", input);
inputString = [NSString stringWithCString:input encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The resulting value of `inputString` is 1.

How do I get the entire value into the string ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading string from input with space character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `%s` in `scanf` it truncate the input at the first space. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first
>   whitespace character found. A terminating null character is
>   automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

You can use this according to [this source](http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/how-to-use-scanf-to-read-string-with-space/):

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", intpu);
```

You can also use `gets()` as an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSLog(@"Enter the string : ");
NSFileHandle *input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData *inputData = [NSData dataWithData:[input availableData]];
NSString *inputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
inputString = [inputString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"%@", inputString);
```

Here try this more precise when talking objective C as the working language

Comment: to reduce number of lines i guess....
[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput] availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

Comment: @KijitDesai sure makes more sense reducing the number of lines, works like a charm.