# Using strstr to determine if a given string contains a string with spaces [C]

Tags: c, string, contains, strstr

I'm working through an example of using the `strstr()` function.

If I input "Pamela Sue Smith", why does the program output ""Pamela" is a sub-string!" and not ""Pamela Sue Smith" is a sub-string!".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void)
{
  char str[72];
  char target[] = "Pamela Sue Smith";

  printf("Enter your string: ");
  scanf("%s", str);

  if (strstr( target, str) != NULL )
    printf(" %s is a sub-string!\n", str);
}
```

Comment: `%s` only reads one word.

Comment: If you want to read a whole line, use `fgets()`, not `scanf()`.

Comment: And you got your arguments to `strstr` swapped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading string from input with space character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character)

Comment: @Barmar: Not quite, it isn't. Though that's part.

Answer (score 3):

1. `main` does not have return-type `void` but `int`.
2. [`scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail. Check the return-value.
   If successful, it returns the number of parameters assigned.
3. `%s` only reads non-whitespace, until the next whitespace (thus 1 word).
4. `%s` does not limit how many non-whitespace characters are read. A buffer-overflow can be deadly.
   Use `%71s` (buffer-size: string-length + 1 for the terminator)
5. You swapped the arguments to [`strstr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html).

Answer (score 3):

From the manual page for `scanf`:

> “s” — Matches  a  sequence  of  non-white-space  characters;  the next
>   pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough
>   to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'),
>   which is added automatically.  **The input string stops  at  white
>   space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.**

So, the part “Sue Smith” never makes it to `str`.  You could use `fgets` which allows you to read a whole line at a time:

```
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
    printf("End of file\n");
    return;
}
```

Note that in this case, `str` contains the terminating end-of-line character.  You could do

```
if (*str != '\0')
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
```

to remove it.
(Also, as some others already pointed out, the “haystack” argument to `strstr` goes first.)