# Reading a string using fgets, couldn't get output of second string

Tags: c, fgets

- Objective of Program :  Get the number of strings to be entered, read the string, reverse the string and print the string. Proceed with the next string

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main() {
      int num_tc, index_tc, char_idx, str_len = 0;
      char S[31];

      scanf("%d\n", &num_tc);

      for (index_tc = 1; index_tc <= num_tc; index_tc++) {
          fgets(S, sizeof(S), stdin);

          /* To compute the string length */
          for (char_idx = 0; S[char_idx] != NULL; char_idx++)
              str_len++;

          /* Reverse string S  */
          for (char_idx = 0; char_idx < str_len / 2; char_idx++) {
              S[char_idx] ^= S[str_len - char_idx - 1];
              S[str_len - char_idx - 1] ^= S[char_idx];
              S[char_idx] ^= S[str_len - char_idx - 1];           
          }
          puts(S);
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Input to the program

  ```
       2<\n>
       ab<\n>
       aba<\n>
  ```

  Output

  ```
      ba
  ```
- Kindly let me know why the second string is not taken for string reversal.
- If I remove string reversal logic, I could see both strings output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not reset `str_len` to `0` in the body of the loop. The length of the second string is incorrect, hence the second string is not properly reversed. Change the loop to:

```
for (str_len = 0; S[str_len] != '\0'; str_len++)
    continue;
```

Note that you should strip the trailing `'\n'` before reversing the string.  You can do this with `S[strcspn(S, "\n")] = '\0';` before computing `str_len`.

Here is a simplified version using `scanf()`, that reverses individual words:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num_tc, tc, len, left, right;
    char buf[31];

    if (scanf("%d\n", &num_tc) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (tc = 0; tc < num_tc; tc++) {
        if (scanf("%30s", buf) != 1)
            break;

        /* Compute the string length */
        for (len = 0; buf[len] != '\0'; len++)
            continue;

        /* Reverse string in buf */
        for (left = 0, right = len - 1; left < right; left++, right--) {
            buf[left] ^= buf[right];
            buf[right] ^= buf[left];
            buf[left] ^= buf[right];           
        }
        puts(buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @gopi_2363: can you mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the grey checkmark below the answer score?

Comment: Sure. 1) S[strcspn(S, "\n")] = '\0'; I am not sure will it be helping in this program. 2) A favour, can we write the same program with scanf (I tried with [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character) ) 3) Is there a better way to put this scanf("%d\n",&num_tc);

Comment: You are supposed to reverse the line contents, prepending a linefeed and appending another linefeed with `puts()` seems inappropriate.  Stripping the linefeed seems the proper semantics. The proposed method for that works in all cases.  You could imagine other methods, such as testing for both `'\0'` and `'\n'` in the loop and forcing a `'\0'` at `S[str_len]`.

Comment: Reading the string with `scanf` will only read a single word.  Your `scanf("%d\n",&num_tc);` seems correct, but it skips any white space after the number, effectively preventing you from inputing an empty line for the reverse phase.  Mixing `scanf` and `fgets()` is tricky.  It would be better to use `fgets()` for both lines and `sscanf()` to parse the number.

Comment: @chqlie : Would apprecate if you can share the same program (reading inputs would be sufficient) all with scanf.