# Strncpy (String C programming) doesn't perform well the second time

Tags: c, string, strncpy

Why does the second strncpy give incorrect weird symbols when printing?
Do I need something like **fflush(stdin)** ?

Note that I used **scanf("%s",aString);** to read an entire string, the input that is entered starts first off with a space so that it works correctly.

```
void stringMagic(char str[], int index1, int index2)
{
    char part1[40],part2[40];

    strncpy(part1,&str[0],index1);
    part1[sizeof(part1)-1] = '\0';//strncpy doesn't always put '\0' where it should
    printf("\n%s\n",part1);

    strncpy(part2,&str[index1+1],(index2-index1));
    part2[sizeof(part2)-1] = '\0';
    printf("\n%s\n",part2);
}
```

**EDIT**
The problem seems to lie in

```
scanf("%s",aString);
```

because when I use **printf("\n%s",aString);** and I have entered something like "Enough with the hello world" I only get as output "Enough" because of the '\0'.

How can I correctly input the entire sentence with whitespace stored? Reading characters?

Now I use: fgets (aString, 100, stdin);
([Reading string from input with space character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character))

Comment: Check if the limits (index1 + 1) and (index2 - index1) actually are within the size of the char array part2. That might be causing it. Then, check if str is actually well formed.

Comment: fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior so you should never do that in any program.

Comment: But up until now that works fine in my program. If you know an alternative I be more than happy to hear it (since sometimes after the first scanf the other scanf will fail)

Answer (score 1):

In order to print a char sequence correctly using `%s`  it needs to be null-terminated. In addition the terminating symbol should be immediately after the last symbol to be printed. However this section in your code: `part2[sizeof(part2)-1] = '\0';` always sets the 39th cell of `part2` to be the 0 character. Note that sizeof(part2) will always return the memory size allocated for `part2` which in this case is 40. The value of this function does not depend on the contents of `part2`.

What you should do instead is to set the `(index2-index1)` character in `part2` to 0. You know you've copied that many characters to part2, so you know what is the expected length of the resulting string.

Comment: But then why is part1 working perfectly fine? I also use there the same line of code. But I understand your point there..

Comment: @HoPam my guess is - pure luck. If you don't set the null terminating character correctly some random data will be printed. However it may happen that the first symbol  after the meaningful content is `\0`. This data is not initialized so it can be anything.

Comment: Will try your method and will let you know ! Thanks !