# scanf validation of input also 1 scanf gets 2 inputs and send it to the next var without needing

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following code lines :

```
printf("enter a number: \n");
if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1)
{ //do some stuff}
else {return 1;}
printf("enter another number: \n");
if (scanf("%d",&y) == 1)
{ //do some stuff}
else {return 1;}
```

the code works but when I'm putting an input to x in the following form "1 1" (1 then space then 1 again) it put the 2nd 1 into y. How can I make it won't happen? it should just stop the code.

I know there are other methods to get inputs but as for now, I'm only allowed to use scanf to get input from the user.

Comment: Then... just stop the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf) or [Reading string from input with space character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character).

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the normal behaviour of `scanf`. The second 1 is read by the
second `scanf` because `%d` skips white spaces until it finds the next number to
convert.

After the first `scanf` this is what is left in the input buffer

```
+-----+-----+------+
| ' ' | '1' | '\n' |
+-----+-----+------+
```

So if you want to stop after the first conversion, you need to clear the buffer.
You can use this function for this:

```
void clear_line(FILE *fp)
{
    if(fp == NULL)
        return;

    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
printf("enter a number: \n");
if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1)
{ //do some stuff}
else {return 1;}

clear_line(stdin);

printf("enter another number: \n");
if (scanf("%d",&y) == 1)
{ //do some stuff}
else {return 1;}

clear_line(stdin);
```

In this case even if you enter `1 1`, the second `scanf` will wait for user
input.

Comment: To be clear, the function `clear_file_buffer` only **read and ignore** from the `FILE *fp` only until the end of the line or end of file.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should rename the function to make it more clear