# scanf fails to read a string in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have a simple C program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char a[100],b[100];
  char *ret;
  printf("Enter the string\n");
  scanf("%s",a);
  printf("Enter the substring to be searched\n");
  scanf("%s",b);
  ret= strstr(a,b);
  if(ret==NULL)
  {
    printf("Substring not found\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Substring found \n");
  }
}
```

When I execute the following program, scanf to read the string into b is not waiting for me to enter the substring and the print statement that prints the `substring not found` is being printed on the console. I tried to give `%s`and tried in the scanf statement and removed `\n` from the printf statements and nothing changed the way it executed the program. It would be great if someone solves this simple problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your inputs, does the first contain a space? The `%s` format specifier stops at the first whitespace character.

Comment: scanf() don’t accept the string with  white space.

Comment: I dont found any mistake in your code.It worked fine for me in gcc. try `
  printf("\nEnter the string");` and  `printf("\nEnter the substring to be searched");` .Use `\n` before.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character

Comment: If i enter `hi how are you` as my main string input the problem exists and second scanf is not waiting for the input and atlast substring not found is being printed. Where as if i enter `heyyyyyyyyyyyy` as my main string input and the second scanf is waiting for me to enter the substring, and i entered `eyyy` and the result is substring found.

Comment: The first string `a` will receive `"hi"` and before you can type anything else the second string `b` will contain `"how"`, which is not a substring of `a`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", variable);` with this scanf will read the whole line, instead of stopping when a space is reached.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char a[100];
  char b[100];
  char *ret;
  printf("Enter the string\n");
  scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", a);

  printf("Enter the substring to be searched\n");
  scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", b);
  ret= strstr(a,b);
  if(ret==NULL)
  {
    printf("Substring not found\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Substring found \n");
  }
}
```

Also you can use `fgets`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char a[100];
  char b[100];
  char *ret;
  printf("Enter the string\n");
  fgets(a,100,stdin);//100 is the size of the string, you could use sizeof()

  printf("Enter the substring to be searched\n");
  fgets(b,100,stdin);//100 is the size of the string, you could use sizeof()
  ret= strstr(a,b);
  if(ret==NULL)
  {
    printf("Substring not found\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Substring found \n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be `%99[^\n]%*c` to prevent a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`, probably the reason is that the spaces are treated as delimiters, and the parts before the space are treated as `a` and the part right after the space will be treated as `b`. Therefore the programme did not prompt you for another input.

For your information: [Reading string from input with space character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Is it fgets or gets?

Comment: Check the information provided, there is an explanation of not using `gets`. `fgets` and `gets` are different.