# Characters after a space is not being printed out

Tags: c++, arrays, char, character, limit

I was using character arrays to get inputs from the user then display the output afterwards. However, every time I enter values with spaces in between, only the first word before the space is printed.

For instance, this is what I typed:

> `Customer No.:` `7877 323 2332`

This will be the output:

> `Customer No.:` `7877`

I already searched for possible solutions but I can't seem to find the right solution.

This is my code for reference:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char custNum[10] = " ";  // The assignment does not allow std::string
    
    cout << "Please enter values for the following: " << endl;
    cout << "Customer No.: ";
    cin >> custNum;
    
    cout << "Customer No.: " << custNum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for not using std::string?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31, we were asked not to use it for the meantime. It would be much easier if we could.

Comment: Hmm.... Okay, anyways, try using `char* str = new char[1];` `scanf("%[^\n]s",str);` instead

Comment: Don't SKIMP on buffer size (e.g. `char custNum[32]`) to read the line as a string requires a minimum of `14` characters (double that and take the next power-of-two for a rough hack)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading string from input with space character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use [std::basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) to read the entire string into the buffer and then remove the spaces with a simple `for` loop. But when using plain-old character arrays *don't skimp on buffer size*. It is far better to be 1000-characters too long than one-character too short. With your input, your absolute minimum size of `custNum` is `14` characters (the `13` shown plus the `'\0'` (nul-terminating) character. (rough rule-of-thumb, take your longest estimated input and double it -- to allow for user-mistake, cat stepping on keyboard, etc...)

In you case you can simply do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    
    char custNum[32] = " ";  // The assignment does not allow std::string
    int wrt = 0;
    
    std::cout << "Please enter values for the following:\nCustomer No.: ";
    
    if (std::cin.getline(custNum, 32)) {    /* validate every input */
    
        for (int rd = 0; custNum[rd]; rd++)
            if (!isspace((unsigned char)custNum[rd]))
                custNum[wrt++] = custNum[rd];
        custNum[wrt] = 0;
        
        std::cout << "Customer No.: " << custNum << '\n';
    }
}
```

The two loop counters `rd` (read position) and `wrt` (write position) are simply used to loop over the original string and remove any whitespace found, nul-terminating again when the loop is left.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readcustnum
Please enter values for the following:
Customer No.: 7877 323 2332
Customer No.: 78773232332
```

Also take a look at [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696) and [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n). Much easier to build good habits now than it is to break bad ones later... Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from std::getline, if you are going to use C-style strings, try the following code:

```
int main() {
    char* str = new char[60];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);  //accepts space a a part of the string (does not give UB as it may seem initially
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Also, if you absolutely need it to be a number, then use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/#:%7E:text=Parses%20the%20C%2Dstring%20str,non%2Dwhitespace%20character%20is%20found.)

```
int ivar = std::atoi(str);
```

---

PS Not to forget gets (!!dangerous!!)

```
char* str;
gets(str);
puts(str);
```

Comment: Now about that misplaced `'s'`? `:)` [man 3 scanf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function(p12)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Seriously man. Now you are just picking on me :( https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282396

Comment: @Quinton417, do not forget to click that little check mark and accept the answer which worked for you

Comment: Also, do take a look at @DavidC.Rankin's answer as well. It is better than mine :)

Comment: Thank you. And I presume you are referring to the comment below the answer you link to above? The `'s'` as you have it will seek to match a literal `'s'` in the input, but since no conversion follows and since a prior successful conversion took place, no *matching failure* or *input failure* results. What it will do is prevent any subsequent conversion specifier from matching. Try and match `scanf("%[^\n]s%d", str, &i)` and then `scanf("%[^\n]%d", str, &i)` (multi-line input required)

Answer (score -1):

`cin >> int_variable` will stop reading input when it reaches the first character that isn't a valid part of a number.  C++ does not consider spaces part of a number, so it stops reading as soon as it encounters one.

You could use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read into a string instead, then remove the spaces from the string before converting to an integer.  Or maybe in this case you don't even need the integer and can leave it as a string.

Comment: The OP is not reading an `int` variable. While it is called "custNum", the declared type is an array of `char`. I think the intent is to store a formatted number (keeping the spaces).

Comment: @JaMiT the definition of `custNum` was edited into the question, I had to guess when I first saw it.

Comment: More precisely, it was restored to the question, but true, it was gone for a while (less than an hour -- in fact it was restored just before you posted this answer). That is why I posted a gentle nudge instead of saying you failed to answer the question. Besides, it would take just a few tweaks to match this answer to the question.

Comment: @JaMiT interesting, that's what I get for not looking at the *whole* edit history.  Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with using `>>` to read strings, so I don't have any confidence in editing my answer to be accurate with this new information.